# Python program to get the value and unit of a person's height？

Tags: python

For example:

- From `170m` I want to get `number:170.0,unit m`
- From `1.059米` I want to get `number:1.059,unit m`
- From `173cm` I want to get `number:173,unit cm`
- From `1m40` I want to get `number：1.40  unit m`
- From `155センチ` I want to get `number:155 unit cm`

My code:

```
value='170cm'
value = re.findall('^\d*\.*\d*|', value)
if len(value) > 0:
    number = value[0]
units = re.findall('m|cm', value)
if len(units) > 0:
    unit = units[0]
```

But I think this it is not good.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I formatted your question so it is easier to read. Can you tell us what the problem with your code is? You told us what you expect to happen, that is the first step. Can you please add the errors you get or describe what you code actually does? That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please explain why it's not good. Make it a function, then show the input and output when called with each of your 5 cases. Try to add the regex to include the Japanese units.

Comment: The regex `'^\d*\.*\d*|'` is too loose, since each of the characters is optional (`*` allows 0 or more repetitions). So it would match ''. Presumably you require at least one digit. So it should be `^\d+\.?\d*`Also your trailing `|` again allows it to match empty-string, you don't need that.

Comment: Also you should use two capture groups in your regex, one for the number, one for the units. Then you should only need one `re.match` call, not two `re.findall` calls. See the doc for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs just a few changes to work as desired for the specified input. One correction has already been suggested by smci:

> The regex `'^\d*.*\d*|'` is too loose, since each of the characters is optional (`*` allows 0 or more repetitions). So it would match ''. Presumably you require at least one digit. So it should be `^\d+.?\d*`Also your trailing `|` again allows it to match empty-string, you don't need that.

I incorporated this and some more changes - see the comments:

```
    numbers = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', value)    # don't overwrite value, you need it below
    if len(numbers) > 0:
        number = numbers[0]
    if len(numbers) > 1:
        number += '.' + numbers[1]              # add the decimals
    # replace the Japanese units with metric ones
    value = value.replace('\xe7\xb1\xb3', 'm').replace('\xe3\x82\xbb\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x83\x81', 'cm')
    units = re.findall('m|cm', value)
    unit = '?'                                  # set default unit in case none present
    if len(units) > 0:
        unit = units[0]
```